# print message when task failed in gradle

Tags: gradle

I'm moving my jar file from build/libs created by the jar task at the end of the build.

```
task move(type: Copy) {
    from 'build/libs'fa
    into 'bin'

}

build.finalizedBy(move)
```

But if the jar file in the bin folder is used, the move task fail but I don't get any output message in the console (except that there is not the "up to date" message).

How do I check if the task didn't succeed and then print a message to the user?

Comment: What does it mean _is used_?

Comment: The jar is a program, if the jar is executed, the file is locked, it cannot be deleted or replaced by another file.

Comment: What is the output when you add `move.doLast { println "Work done: ${move.didWork}" }`?

Comment: It returns true.
It actually looks like the task always succeed. I can't delete the jar file when it's being used, but I can replace it with a newer version. The reason I thought it wasn't succeeding was because I couldn't do that when I compiling manually using javac+jar commands instead of gradle. I don't understand why the jar from javac and gradle don't behave the same, but if it's working, it's all good. Thanks.

Comment: Note that the behavior may be platform-dependent. Windows will lock files that are in use, while most other platforms will not.